# Canceling/detatching a listener from firebase snapshots when a certain criteria is met

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a listener for a firebase collection which shall listen to changes until a certain criteria is met, e.g. a field in the data is true. Building the listener is easy, but I cannot find out how to cancel the listener from within the listener:

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var subscription = db.collection("cities").doc("SF").snapshots().listen((event) {
      var data = event.data();
      if (data["x"] == true) {
        subscription.cancel(); // subscription is not defined yet, so this won't compile.
      }
    });
```

How to cancel the listener from within?

Comment: what about getting the data as a `Future`, then if the condition is met, then it should start the listener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define subscription as nullable type.

```dart
// import dart:async at page top.
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?
    subscription;
subscription = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("cities")
    .doc("SF")
    .snapshots()
    .listen((event) {
  var data = event.data();
  if (data["x"] == true) {
    subscription?.cancel(); // subscription is defined
  }
});
```